# Sendgrid - is it possible to have subscription tracking without inserting the unsubscribe link?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

Our current implementation allows for a custom unsubscribe link to inserted into the email body. Clicking on the link directs the user to a page on our server where they can unsubscribe from our mailing list.

We currently listen and record message events from sendgrid (received, open, unsubscribe).

I want to add the list-unsubscribe headers that when the user clicks unsubscon the email detail dropdown, creates an unsubscribe message event. I've turned on Subscription Tracking which is doing this correctly - but also appending an unsubscribe link which isn't necessary because we have them already inserted in the message body. Is it possible to have the list unsubscribe headers but not have the unsubscribe message appended.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is how Gmail specifically treats recieved messages containing a `List-Unsubscribe` header. This behavior is baked into Gmail itself and cannot be disabled without removing the header from your message entirely.

SendGrid's docs have [a section speaking explicitly to this Gmail-specific behavior](https://sendgrid.com/en-us/blog/list-unsubscribe#bgmail-listunsubscribe-headerb).

Comment: Right - I want SendGrid to add the List-Unsubscribe header and record the unsubscribe message event **without** appending the additional unsubscribe text to the end of the sent email.